# Almost Surely Finite Stopping Time Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Assume $\tau$ is a $\mathcal{F}_n$- stopping time such that there exists a positive integer $m$ and some $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $n$

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau\leq n+m \,\, \vert \mathcal{F}_n) >\epsilon$$

Show that for every positive integer $k$

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau>km)\leq(1-\epsilon)^k$$

[This was really helpful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82055/almost-surely-finite-stopping-time):

Since $\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, the set $ (\tau>n)\in\mathcal{F}_n$, so

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau \leq n+ m, \tau>n)>\epsilon\mathbb{P}(\tau >n)$$

Since $\mathbb{P}(n<\tau \leq n+ m) = \mathbb{P}(\tau>n) - \mathbb{P}(\tau>n+m),$ combining we get

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau>n+m)\leq(1-\epsilon)\mathbb{P}(\tau>n)$$

**Here's were I get lost** The referenced link then says "iterating on multiples of k, we get"
$$\mathbb{P}(\tau>km)\leq(1-\epsilon)^k$$

**How do I show this last bit?** Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Your argument shows that $\Bbb P(\tau>km)\le(1-\epsilon)\Bbb P(\tau>(k-1)m)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots$. (Take your $n$ equal to $k-1$.) Proceed recursively.